# How I can read a sheet of Excel from SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

Please need to help for this problem that I have. I need to read a sheet of Excel 2007 from SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to read this data what contains data and store in a temporal table. But right now I am having problems with read Excel because it shows me an error from SQL Server. What I need for reading it

> Error: Not registered the OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

I hope you can help me with it problem, please.

I have executed it. Maybe I am missing something. My operating system is Windows 7 64bit

Code:

```
SELECT * 
INTO TB_EXAMPLE 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Microsoft\Test.xls; HDR=YES; IMEX=1', 'SELECT * FROM [Plan1$]') 
GO
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about [linked servers](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2018/using-a-sql-server-linked-server-to-query-excel-files/) and [more information here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a808e6df-9fcf-4801-9d9e-bb658d4e54d6/excel-2013-64-bit-workbook-as-a-linked-server-for-64-bit-sql-server-2012?forum=sqldataaccess)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

This will register the OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

Comment: I have installed it but it not works yet. it shows the same error.

Comment: There is a 2010 version that may work if the 2007 version didn't work - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 You should check if you need the 32 or 64 bit version as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028775/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-is-not-registered