# How to install Microsoft.Ace.oledb 32 bit with Office 64-bit?

Tags: ssis

I was trying to create a SSIS package where i want to upload an excel file into my DB but its giving me an error that

> Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0 is not registered on your local machine

I have installed the 64-bit version of the MS Access Engine and it perfectly installed but after that i am still unable to create DTS package.
I have searched over the internet and found that there are two versions available for this and i have downloaded both and when i try to install the 32-bit version of the Access Engine it gives me error

> You cannot install the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 because you currently have 64-bit Office products installed.

Please help me on this i am really looking forward to it.

Comment: Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028775/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-is-not-registered

Comment: I already check this post ... i have removed the Access engine 64-bit from my laptop and now i am trying to install 32-bit but the issue remains the same.

Comment: There is a setting called use 64bit runtime that needs to be set to off.  Have you done that?

Comment: Nope. Can you please tell me how should i turn it off ?

Comment: In visual studio its under project properties.  This page has a screenshot https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx  Depending on how you deploy to production there are different methods.  This article covers some. http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/02/is-my-ssis-package-running-in-32-or-64.html

Comment: I'm still facing the same problem, unable to install the 32-bit version of MS Access Engine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This solution no longer works. It seems to have changed so instead of /passive, now the install requires /quiet

Comment: just confirming that /quiet still works.

Comment: Suggest monitoring of the Event Viewer since otherwise you have no idea when it succeeds or fails the installation due to the /quiet flag.

Comment: Also, the same solution works for installing the AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe with the /quiet flag if you happen to have 32-bit office installed and need the X64 version of the Access db engine.

Answer (score 18):

Somehow late to the party but nevertheless:

[source](https://blog.codefluententities.com/2011/01/20/microsoft-access-database-engine-2010-redistributable/)

> > To install the Microsoft ACE OLEDB Provider 32-bit on a machine running Office 2010 64-bit:
> > *install using cmd with the following command:*
>
> $yourPath$\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /passive

Comment: Thank you so much!!  It works and my problem is solved now :) @idobre

Comment: glad I could help. I remember this issue from when I've started working with SSIS (and Excel).

Answer (score 0):

This solution works when installing ACE 32bit on with 64bit Office **$yourPath$\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /quiet**
Thank you sir

Comment: Please make more obvious what insight your post provides in addition to existing answers. Currently your post gives an impression of merely saying thanks to the answer which already outlined this solution.

Comment: @Yunnosch Users < 10 rep do not have the right to comment. This would probably have been a comment elsewise. It was the only way how the user could write something.

Comment: @Yunnosch Or 50, yes. I just wanted to mention the likely cause of such answers. I know how it was as a new user when I could not add comments but I still wanted to add some points, it is not nice :). In this case, the first comment here should refer to the commenting privilege problem and less to the content. It is not the first time that critical comments show little awareness of this.

Comment: @Yunnosch I get your point, that way will win on the long run. And more than that, the answer also might still a little bit indeed, since the full code line is now available in the search results while it would be less obvious just as a comment or spread across two answers. An edit might have been better, but anyway, I withdraw from the field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue to and I tried to use the /quite but it's stating that The system cannot find the path specified.