# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, oledb, aceoledb

I get this error when I try to connect to any excel through MSSQL Server Data Import i.e. SSIS package The `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` provider is not registered on the local machine. (`System.Data`)

It is not the same version I think some other patching is needed

Comment: I don't see why this question was voted to be closed as a duplicate...  It's clearly a newer version in the error message and needs a newer set of components!  This question and answers helped me for my `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` issues.  The question being pointed to by the close request is for `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` and the answers address THAT version.  This question should be opened back up.

Comment: @ArvoBowen No problem. I reopened it. But both questions have the same solution.

Comment: How so?  They are different versions requiring different downloads.  They are related but have different solutions.  If I followed the answer from the other question it would not solve my issue.

Answer (score 255):

For anyone that is still stuck on this issue after trying the above.  If you are right-clicking on the database and going to tasks->import, then here is the issue.  Go to your start menu and under sql server, find the x64 bit import export wizard and try that.  Worked like a charm for me, but it took me FAR too long to find it Microsoft!

Comment: To have Excel available from the 64-bit version of DTSWizard, install the 2016 Access Database Engine redistributable:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Source:
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2017/06/11/sql-server-2016-import-and-export-wizard-and-excel.aspx

I tested this myself and this works. Note that SSDT is a 32-bit application so if you launch the import/export wizard from it, it's the 32-bit version of the wizard that launches. This is still the case even as of Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very useful. I have Office (2016) 64-bit and SQL 64-bit AND the corresponding connector Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0. However I was getting the message "'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." This simply did not make sense. After opening directly the Import wizard 64-bit I did not have any problem to import excel files. My impression is that by default the tasks->import path goes to the 32-bit wizard and that messes up with the 64-bit items, not sure. Thanks Paul.

Comment: @otravers, I downloaded and installed the 2016 Access Database Engine redistributable, but it didn't help. Then it hit me, that's for Access, not Excel.

Comment: @Rod, despite the name, I assure you this does solve this specific issue with Excel and DTSWizard.

Comment: @Coffee, yes, if you launch DTSWizard from SSMS, it's the 32-bit version that will open up.

Comment: I don't have a x64 version of the Import/Export wizard

Comment: This worked for me. From SQL Management no can't go, from import wizard, works nicely

Comment: Thank you.  In my case, it is called SQL Server 2017 Import and Export Data(64-bit).   Yes, it works like a charm.

Comment: @Paul Dove I cannot find the x64 bit import export wizard and/or the start menu..I am using SQL Sever Management Studio v17.9 and if I go to Tools I see option Import and Export Settings which is different

Comment: I found the following information important - Microsoft does not mark the 64 bit version with a name that is different from the 32 bit version.   My files show the 64 bit version (AceOledb16) as 153 MB 16.0.5044.1000 and the 32 bit version as 137 MB 16.0.5044.1000.   It's important to see which version you have installed.  Microsoft, can you please fix this?

Comment: The 64-bit import/export wizard doesn't get installed with SSMS. You need to install SQL Server locally to get that tool.

Comment: Aug 8 2023 Office 2016 updates broke this.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".
Error: 0xC020801C at Fill Excel Calendar, Destination - CalendarImport [36]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "DestinationConnectionExcel" failed with error code 0xC0209302.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Answer (score 144):

Note: I am running SQL 2016 Developer 64bit, Office 2016 64bit.

I had the same issue and solved it by downloading the following:

1. Download and install this:
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920
2. Whatever file you are trying to access/import, make sure you select it as a  Office 2010 file (even though it might be a Office 2016 file).

It works.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb)

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, thanks! Did load my office 2016 file as office 2007-2010 and it worked well. So much better than trying CSV/TSV.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that I *shouldn't* choose Office 2016. Not sure I would've tried one of the other ones.

Comment: The first link is broken

Comment: I just updated the link to the current URL for Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable

Comment: On a WS 2016 64Bit I had to use the 32Bit version to get it working...

Comment: Had to run the (32bit) installer from command line with /quiet flag. Then it worked. Otherwise it was complaining.

Comment: A key element here is that you have to have *SQL Server 64-bit* installed on your own computer. Simply installing MSSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) won't do it, because MSSMS is *always* 32-bit, while your 64-bit Office will only let you install the 64-bit version of  the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable (which won't work with the 32-bit MSSMS).

Answer (score 39):

As a quick workaround I just saved the workbook as an Excel 97-2003 .xls file.  I was able to import with that format with no error.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Got an, "Unexpected error from external database driver (1). (Microsoft JET Database Engine)"

Comment: It took a  couple of tries but in the end I found this the quickest solution to my problem.

Comment: This only works if you have less than 64K rows to import.

Comment: Careful that your spreadsheet does not have more than 65,536 rows, otherwise you can lose data doing this conversion.

Comment: Quick and easy solution for time sensitive problem. Can't seem to find the stand alone import export wizard despite having VS22 with SSTD installed.

Answer (score 35):

If you have OS(64bit) and SSMS(64bit) and already install the **AccessDatabaseEngine(64bit)** and you still received an error, try this following solutions:

1: direct opening the sql server import and export wizard.

if you able to connect using direct sql server import and export wizard, then importing from SSMS is the issue, it's like activating 32bit if you import data from SSMS.

Instead of installing **AccessDatabaseEngine(64bit)** , try to use the **AccessDatabaseEngine(32bit)** , upon installation, windows will stop you for continuing the installation if you already have another app installed , if so , then use the following steps. This is from the **MICROSOFT**. The Quiet Installation.

**If Office 365 is already installed, side by side detection will prevent the installation from proceeding. Instead perform a /quiet install of these components from command line. To do so, download the desired AccessDatabaseEngine.exe or AccessDatabaeEngine_x64.exe to your PC, open an administrative command prompt, and provide the installation path and switch Ex: C:\Files\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /quiet**

or check in the **Addition Information** content from the **link below**,

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: Wow this was a frustrating one. Turns out the SSMS 18.5 installer is 64bit, but the application itself is 32 bit. I kept installing the 64bit AccessDatabaseEngine office components with the same error. Looked at task manager, saw SSMS is 32 bit... Then, I used your method: C:\Files\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /quiet because I have 64bit Office 2016 installed. This worked!! It successfully installed the 32bit database engine alongside 64bit office.

Comment: Try to use the AccessDatabaseEngine(32bit) works for me.

Comment: I have 64bit office. Install the 64 bit components. Still had the error. Running 32 bit installer fails just opening it. Ran the 32 bit installer from command line and import is now working.

Comment: This really helped...i was just trying with 64 bit blindly as i know OS is 64, office is 64 bit.

Comment: This really works. Best answer for Win10 64bit OS.

Answer (score 17):

An alternative that works for me is to simply convert to a CSV.

Comment: To great problems, great solutions, thank you @PeterX

Comment: Worked like a charm! I just needed to select flat file instead of ms excel 2016 when I was uploading the csv.

Comment: Great! When the 'better' way doesn't work, use the 'easier' way... :)

Comment: This works for me - Office 365 - Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2305 Build 16.0.16501.20074) 64-bit - SQL Server Management Studio 19.1.56.0

Answer (score 12):

Against other answers here, you can just install "ACEDB driver 64-bit" next to the other 64-bit Microsoft program.

In my case, I had **"Microsoft 365"** 64-bit (Microsoft **Office 365**) installed.

Because of the error

> 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local
> machine. (System.Data)

I tried installing [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920). But I got errors for 32-bit and 64-bit installers.

64-bit:

> You cannot install the 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016 because you currently have 64-bit Office products
> installed. If you want to install 32-bit Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016, you will first need to remove the 64-bit installation of
> Office products. After uninstalling the following product(s), rerun
> setup in order to install 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016: Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit
> Registration

or 32-bit:

> You cannot install the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016 because you currently have 64-bit Office products
> installed. If you want to install 32-bit Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016, you will first need to remove the 64-bit installation of
> Office products. After uninstalling the following product(s), rerun
> setup in order to install 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database
> Engine 2016: Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit
> Registration

I could not uninstall single components:

[image]

The steps:

0. **No need to uninstall and reinstall anything.**
1. Press "Download" at [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

[image]

2. Choose `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe`. No need to install 32-bit `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe`, against other answers.

[image]

3. Run the executable from **command prompt**. Do not forget to add `/quiet`, else, it will not work:

   ```
   C:\Users\myuser\Downloads>AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe /quiet
   ```
4. Press OK for the administrator rights if asked for.

After this, my macro could fetch data from an Excel worksheet. I checked my local Microsoft Access of the Microsoft 365 package and it still worked.

Credits go to [You cannot install the 32/64 bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine because you currently have 64/32 bit Office](https://superuser.com/questions/1557350/you-cannot-install-the-32-64-bit-version-of-microsoft-access-database-engine-bec/) and its source at [How to install Microsoft.Ace.oledb 32 bit with Office 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60916304/11154841).

Comment: Very good instructions! In my case 32 bit fixed the problem.

Comment: @Basssprosse That is helpful, it clearly depends on the system, yours probably 32 bit then? Or put it easier, if the 64 bit does not work, check 32 bit of course.

Comment: Oh, yeah, curiously my office-version is 32bit. I thought it is 64bit. Thank you!

Comment: I tried just installing this with the exe but it didn't work. I finally went through the process of using command prompt and /quiet and it did work. Can anyone explain to me why this is necessary?

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 11 Enterprise when I ran the 64 and 32-bit in silent via the command line.  Thanks!

Comment: Vor me, this command line, run within Administrator account, did it:
accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe /quiet

The /passive option did not work.

Answer (score 6):

If you have ***Office 365***:

1. Download 32 Bit version [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)
2. Run Command Prompt as Administrator --> C:\Downloads\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /quiet
3. Close SSMS & Reopen, Try Importing File again.

Doesnt work?

4. Download 64 bit version [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)
5. Run Command Prompt as Administrator --> C:\Downloads\AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe /quiet
6. Close SSMS & Reopen, Import File.

Note:
Path to dowbloaded executable might be "C:\Downloads\User\***USERNAME***\Downloads\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe" for example

Comment: My MS office-version is 32bit, so this solution worked for me!

Comment: I run both with /quiet

Answer (score 5):

ACE.oledb.16.0 dosen't work in the 64-bit os

download patch from
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: It did not work I tried still getting the same error

Comment: it works for importing Microsoft Excel 2007-2010 on SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

Answer (score 1):

You have to use now the new ***XLSX***-Driver from Access-Redist (32/64-Bit).
The current XLS-Driver are corrupted since last cumulative update.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Go [here][1], download `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable` and install
2. Close SQL Server Management Studio
3. Go to Start Menu -> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 ->  SQL Server 2017 Import and Export Data (64-bit)
4. Open the application and try to import data using the "Excel 2016" option, it should work fine.

Comment: Tried... Step 1-4, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: this worked for me; thank you

Answer (score 0):

After having both installed the *Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable* and found the *x64 bit import export wizard* as instructed in the answers above, I had one last hoop to jump through. I got this error 'Executing the query "CREATE TABLE ...." failed with the following error: "**Culture is not supported** ... **3072 (0x0c00) is an invalid culture identifier**."'

The fix was to go to Control Panel -> Clock and Region -> change my "English (Finland)" region to pure Finnish (Finland). Other more traditional cultures such as en-US will work too. I think I first saw this solution here: [Fix culture is not supported: 3072 by changing Region Formats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/188182)

Comment: I tried all  solution above and nothing worked, in my setup I don't have SQL Server on my local machine, only SSMS. I will not install it.   I think it's a BIG difference between installed and registered. Message said Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. How can I check my registry or some other places ????