# This is a problem arised during importing a excel workbook data into Microsoft SQL DBMS

Tags: data-import, dbms-output

### TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

The operation could not be completed.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

This what DBMS SQL shows when I am importing data from excel into DBMS. What is the solution for this

I didn't try anything. Also I am expecting the data to be imported to MY SQL DBMS properly without any error

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360932/microsoft-ace-oledb-16-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-sys)