# import and export wizard - data source - there is missing option excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, import, datasource

Im trying to import data from excel to Microsoft sql manager studio.
Im using import and export wizard.
When I want to choose data source, there is no excel. What can I do to have also an option excel?
Thanks

Comment: Well, I ve found that there is an option flat file source (.txt). So I can use it instead of excel. But still Im interested about adding excel as a type of source, if anybody has some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Also, you can convert to csv and import comma delimited.

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: I believe you have to have excel installed (either on the machine ssms is running or on the sql server machine itself, I forget which) in order to do this

Answer (score 1):

You need a provider for excel.  On a workstation it should get installed with Excel.  On a server there are a few options that are easily found with a web search. "SSIS Excel Provider"

Here is a post that references the topic
[Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028775/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-is-not-registered)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install this 64 bit driver: [Driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255)

After that it should work.